# Why is Chrome's session per user rate higher than other browsers'?

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome, session

I'm trying to figure out why the Chrome's session/user rate is higher than that of other browsers.

[image]

More specifically the session/user rate for each browser is:

[image]

Does it mean something for Chrome users? Why do Chrome users do multiple sessions while other browser users don't? Or is it by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be few reasons that I can think of. I'll name just 3 for now:

1. Your website user experience is better on Chrome and worse in other browsers. In other words maybe on other browsers your website is not rendering properly, maybe there are some bugs, buttons not working or it simply looks bad on mobile/desktop I'm safari. Quote often website developers are focused on testing the website on Chrome and forget to make sure to make it compatible with other browsers
2. Maybe your website content is not relevant enough for iPhone/Mac users? If you have articles about Android latest updates then no wonder that people using iPhones are not interested?
3. Maybe you don't have enough data for Chrome users. On the screenshot you provided I can see that Chrome has fewest number of users comparing to other browsers so it might be that if the numbers were even you would have similar data

Answer (score -3):

It is true that Chrome's session is more at user rate for other browsers. One of the solid reasons for this is that Google is the world's number 1 search engine and it has a large number of users in the world. Chrome is Google's product. For this reason, most of the users give importance to Chrome. We all know that Google is known for a time to time of changes and its strict guideline, which makes it different from others, Other search engines cannot do this.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.   Why would Google owning a search engine as well as a browser encourage users to visit more often?  What do Googles "strict guidelines" have to do with the sessions per user ratio?